I cannot Install Brave under on Debian 10
I have been trying to install brave-browser, so far to no avail. I installed it successfully before. But I wanted to upgrade it. In the process I did:
sudo apt purge brave-browser

and when I tried to install it again:
patitomora@angel-pc:~$ sudo apt-get install brave-browser
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  brave-keyring
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  brave-browser brave-keyring
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
Need to get 108 MB/108 MB of archives.
After this operation, 337 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable/main amd64 brave-browser amd64 1.51.110
  404  Not Found [IP: 3.161.4.59 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/pool/main/b/brave-browser/brave-browser_1.51.110_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 3.161.4.59 443]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

that appears, I already tried:
sudo apt update --fix-missing

and other methods, without any success. Any help?

This is the sources list for the Brave Browser on my system:
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list
deb [arch=amd64] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable main


Please edit your question and provide the output of:
LANG=C sudo apt-get install brave-browser but even without it, I can say that your APT repo is broken.

oh sorry i did not realize

Did you try to run apt-get update plain?

It just looks you didn't run apt-get update. Here all works.

This appears to have been a temporary issue, but Debian 10 lost regular support (due to being old) on 10 September 2022, so they might stop packaging Brave for Debian 10 at any time. You should really consider upgrading your Debian (at least to 11 which is supported until later this year, but preferably to 12 which is the current stable release).

Agreeing with @Henriksupportsthecommunity, twice so as using Brave browser indicates you're security-conscious, and what good is using Brave if you're on a system without security updates?

EDIT this might have been a temporary hickup, check whether it's working now. If you use any special HTTP proxies, do check they work.

It seems you set up the repository according to Brave's instructions. Sadly, the URL from these instructions doesn't actually point to anything that seems to be a debian package repo.
So, I'm afraid, at this point there's nothing you can do to solve that. Brave seems to have not foreseen backup repos anywhere.
You could remove the brave-browser-release.list file, and install brave browser as flatpak package from https://flathub.org/apps/com.brave.Browser ; however, for a project that emphasizes verifiable trust as much as Brave does, it isn't possible to verify the origin of the binaries you install, as far as I can tell.
Frankly, I find that brave offers nothing that firefox with the uBlock origin and privacy badger addons don't deliver (you can also add the HTTPS Anywhere extension, but it's becoming less necessary these days); using Tor with any browser on debian is easy and there are many guides. What firefox definitely has as a feature over brave is a lack of praise by questionable Cryptocurrency Bros™; entanglement with the cryptocurrency & NFT community is, in my personal opinion, much more of a security downside than all the conflicts of interest that companies like Google have with respecting their users' privacy, considering the substantial damage that is the track record of people pushing blockchain solutions to distributed non-problems.
So, what I'd recommend is that you, while Brave is sorting out how to get secure software securely to actual users, try using firefox with the aforementioned plugins, and via Tor, should you wish to use that (there's also privacy implications of using Tor, with it seeming likely that a relevant amount of exit nodes being operated by secret services and user-hostile entities; it's not a panacea).

Being a probable AWS or AWS-like "s3" URL I'm not surprised it doesn't provide navigation. I went to https://brave.com/latest/ took note the last version is "Release Notes 1.64.113 (Mar 27, 2024)" and changed OP's url into: https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/pool/main/b/brave-browser/brave-browser_1.64.113_amd64.deb . This one (today) does provide a package to download (eg: using Firefox or curl).

the problem is that there's no /dists/ entry, @A.B

Just went on, applied the setup on a Debian 10 container and got: apt --print-uris update | grep brave | grep Release => https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/dists/stable/InRelease . Again I don't expect to be able to navigate within S3.

@A.B hm, interesting, I threw the website's same instructions into podman before I wrote that answer, and did get a 404. But you are right, your URL works?

Yes I could download the two packages with apt. I didn't test if it worked (ie: if it's actually compatible with Debian 10).

@A.B fair enough, because that's not what OP was asking about; glad it works! I could tear down my answer at that point, aside from the "if it still persists, check your proxy" part.
